# execv error: Exec format error Running RPCS3

Tags: command-line, 20.04, permissions, emulation

Fairly new Linux user here.

I'm currently attempting to install the RPCS3 PlayStation emulator on my Ubuntu 20.04 system for an AI related project I'm working on. Following the guides provided, I completed the following steps:

1. In the console, run `wget --content-disposition https://rpcs3.net/latest-appimage` to download the file. This ram successfully.
2. Run `chmod a+x ./filename` to make the file executable. This appears to have worked correctly, and in the file's permissions tab it is checked as executable.
3. Run the file with `./filename` At which point I receive the error `execv error: Exec format error`

With some cursory research, I was able to find the basics of what this error means. Unfortunately, every solution I could find was either very situation-specific or a bit esoteric for my lack of Linux experience, so I'm having a hard time figuring out where to go from here. Any recommendations for how to proceed are greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I should specify it is a .AppImage file

Comment: There does seem to be something odd about the file - in particular, `readelf -h` shows an `ABI Version` of 65... not sure what that means, but the loader doesn't seem to like it

Comment: @steeldriver I see, do you think going with an older version of the program might resolve the issue?

Comment: yes worth a try I think

Comment: @steeldriver I was able to find a workaround with an old version. Thank you for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I seem to have found a workaround. In case anyone else has this very specific issue here is what I did:

1. Go to the RPCS3 downloads page and click "Download Previous Builds"
2. Find an older version. In my case I downloaded the 0.0.12-11117 build. You may have to try a couple before you find one that works
3. Run `chmod a+x ./filename` to make the file executable
4. Execute the file. At this point the emulator should open and prompt you to update it. In my case I was able to update it safely and still run it

Hope this helps some stray soul some day